# Help Translating Cemetery Monument Engraving in German

Tags: translation, german-to-english

[image]

This is my 3x Great-Grandmother's cemetery monument.Her name was Johannetta Muller. She was born in Kirchen, Altenkirchen, Germany in 1837 and died in Cincinnati, Ohio, USA January 15th or 16th in 1875. I am having a difficult time understanding the rest of the engraving. Any help would be appreciated!

Elizabeth

Comment: The first name on the grave stone reads _Johannette_ (with a final _e_). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to edit.

---

> Hier ruhet in Gott
> Johannette
> Müller,
> aus Kirchen
> Regierungsbezirk Koblenz
> Preußen
> gest. 15 Jan 1875

Which translates to

Here rests in god
Johannette
Müller,
from Kirchen
District Koblenz
Prussia
died on 15th January 1875

Comment: The first name reads _Johannette_, while the question says _Johannetta_ But I think it is rather clear that the last letter is an _e_.

Comment: I kind of see "Hier ruhet in Gott", which was also common, but we would need a higher resulution version to be sure. The last part is hard to decipher.

Comment: Definitely "Hier ruhet in Gott".

Comment: "Hier ruhet in Gott" is also confirmed by comparison. An image search turns up plenty of headstones beginning with that phrase, but here are two in Frakturschrift, with the peculiar Fraktur "G" in "Gott": ["frühes Verkehrsopfer](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rolfdietrichbrecher/25099453207) and ["Evangeliest"](https://www.mainpost.de/regional/main-spessart/bei-kindergartenneubau-einen-evangelisten-gefunden-art-10532563).

Comment: Yes, the G is huge in Fraktur. Thanks, I'm pretty much convinced now that it's not "unvergessen", so I'll edit again.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely _ruhet in Gott_. Great team-work @HalvarF!